# Entity Framework - How to add a columns from Code tables to current entity

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have two tables.

One table is `codes_table` with 3 columns `type`, `code_id`, `code_name`.

It holds rows like:

```
type   code_id    code_name
---------------------------
Color    1        Red
Color    2        Blue
Color    3        Green
Size     1        Small
Size     2        Medium
Price    1        Cheep
```

etc.

The second table (let's call it `Products`) contains a column called `COLOR_ID`.

I don't think that it possible to create a foreign-key from the second table to the first table.

Now, I want to return all entities from the table Products (i.e. the second table), and that each entity will include the COLOR_NAME according to its COLOR_ID. (i.e. Im trying to retrieve the color_name from table 1 into table 2 accorind to the color_id)

I an using EF6 running on VS2013, which connecting to oracle 11G through ODP 12.1.24.

How can I do that using Entity Framework?
Is there a Linq query that can retrieve the merged data?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, try something yourself. At least show your code where you get Products using EntityFramework.

Comment: This piece of code returns Products:


using(var context = new MyContext())
{
  var products = from p in context.Products select p;
  var res = products.ToArray();
}

Comment: do you have `Color` navigation property inside `Product` class?

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) - point #1 - "common lookup tables". This is a **bad** idea - don't do it! If you have three different kinds of lookups - use **three** tables, so you can establish **foreign key** constraints to ensure your data quality!

Comment: Thanks Adil, 
  Yes, I have a color_id inside

Comment: Thanks marc_s, but this is the situation, and I cant change the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nested from in linq:

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    var result = (from product in ctx.Products
                  from code in ctx.Codes.Where(c => product.colorId == c.code_id && c.type == "Color").DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new {product, code}).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I want to have My product entity enriched with the color name.

Is there a way to add some kind of function/linq property to the Product EF-table?

Comment: @Nir you can use a dto class (for example ProductWithColorDto) and inject the result of this query to it. or you can use a not mapped column in Product class and set the color on it in code.

Comment: Thanks ArMaN, 
I was able to add the color-name to my product using your advice.
Yet, I hoped that the framework will provide an automatic way to match the results (instead of me running over the list and update the color-name property).
Thanks again.